# datetime with string.Template

Tags: python, string, templates

Inside a template passed to `string.Template` I want to apply a custom format for a datetime object.

The following code does NOT work, but I would like to end up with something like this:

```py
from datetime import datetime as dt
import string

print('{:%a, %d.%m.%Y at %H:%M}'.format(dt.now()))
print(string.Template("${dt:%a, %d.%m.%Y at %H:%M}").substitute({"d": dt.now()}))
```

The first line will work without any error, but the second will fail with `ValueError: Invalid placeholder in string: line 1, col 1`

Comment: I don't think string templates support formatting directives out of the box, only simple substitutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> print(string.Template("{$d:%a, %d.%m.%Y at %H:%M}").substitute({"d": dt.now()}))
```

{2022-04-19 10:51:57.409244:%a, %d.%m.%Y at %H:%M}

i got past the invalid placeholder error by moving $ to d. but the formatting is not as expected

Answer (score 0):

The following works (tested on Python 3.9) - to the best of my understanding as to what the OP meant

```
from string import Template
print(Template("$datetime").substitute(datetime=dt.now().strftime('%a, %d.%m.%Y at %H:%M')))
```